# Background repeat problems and moving divs in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I don't have any code to show as it is on a intranet system. However I have noticed a couple of weird things when looking at it in IE6. This isn't the usual box model problem or IE6 rendering things differently.

One thing that I noticed is on a div where I have a gradient background with repeat-x attribute. When the page loads in IE6 (and any other browser) it looks fine. However when I scroll down the page and back the background appears to repeat in the y direction too?!

Also I have a footer div, which is flush to the content. Again at first this is fine. However when I scroll it off the page and back there appears a gap, which gets bigger when I scroll off and back again. Once more returns it to what it originally (and should) looked.

Are there known IE6 rendering bugs  for such problems or is it just bad coding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding zoom: 1 to blocks with problems. If it works — it's hasLayout problem.